# Fast python algorithm (in numpy or pandas?) to find indices of array elements that match elements in another array

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, numpy, pandas

I am looking for a fast method to determine the *cross-matching indices* of two arrays, defined as follows.

I have two very large (>1e7 elements) structured arrays, one called *members*, and another called *groups*. Both arrays have a *groupID* column. The *groupID* entries of the *groups* array are unique, the *groupID* entries of the *members* array are not.

The *groups* array has a column called *mass*. The *members* array has a (currently empty) column called *groupmass*. I want to assign the correct *groupmass* to those elements of *members* with a *groupID* that matches one of the groups. This would be accomplished via:

```
members['groupmass'][idx_matched_members] = groups['mass'][idx_matched_groups]
```

So what I need is a fast routine to compute the two index arrays *idx_matched_members* and *idx_matched_groups*. This sort of task seems so common that it seems very likely that a package like numpy or pandas would have an optimized solution. Does anyone know of a solution, professionally developed, homebrewed, or otherwise?

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with `pandas` using `map` to map the data from one column using the data of another.  Here's an example with sample data:

```
members = pandas.DataFrame({
    'id': np.arange(10),
    'groupID': np.arange(10) % 3,
    'groupmass': np.zeros(10)
})

groups = pandas.DataFrame({
    'groupID': np.arange(3),
    'mass': np.random.randint(1, 10, 3)
})
```

This gives you this data:

```
>>> members
   groupID  groupmass  id
0        0          0   0
1        1          0   1
2        2          0   2
3        0          0   3
4        1          0   4
5        2          0   5
6        0          0   6
7        1          0   7
8        2          0   8
9        0          0   9
>>> groups
   groupID  mass
0        0     3
1        1     7
2        2     4
```

Then:

```
>>> members['groupmass'] = members.groupID.map(groups.set_index('groupID').mass)
>>> members
   groupID  groupmass  id
0        0          3   0
1        1          7   1
2        2          4   2
3        0          3   3
4        1          7   4
5        2          4   5
6        0          3   6
7        1          7   7
8        2          4   8
9        0          3   9
```

If you will often want to use the groupID as the index into `groups`, you can set it that way permanently so you won't have to use `set_index` every time you do this.

Comment: that is exactly the functionality I was looking for. I just played around with some fake data of very large size, and the map routine is lightning fast and quite robust. Pandas is so damn awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of setting the `mass` with just `numpy`.  It does use iteration, so for large arrays it won't be fast.

For just 10 rows, this is much faster than the `pandas` equivalent.  But as the data set becomes larger (eg. M=10000), `pandas` is much better.  The setup time for `pandas` is larger, but the per row iteration time much lower.

Generate test arrays:

```
dt_members = np.dtype({'names':['groupID','groupmass'], 'formats': [int, float]})
dt_groups =  np.dtype({'names':['groupID', 'mass'], 'formats': [int, float]})

N, M = 5, 10
members = np.zeros((M,), dtype=dt_members)    
groups = np.zeros((N,), dtype=dt_groups)
members['groupID'] = np.random.randint(101, 101+N, M)
groups['groupID'] = np.arange(101, 101+N)
groups['mass']  = np.arange(1,N+1)

def getgroup(id):
    idx = id==groups['groupID']
    return groups[idx]

members['groupmass'][:] = [getgroup(id)['mass'] for id in members['groupID']]
```

In `python2` the iteration could use `map`:

```
members['groupmass'] =  map(lambda x: getgroup(x)['mass'], members['groupID'])
```

---

I can improve the speed by about 2x by minimizing the repeated subscripting, eg.

```
def setmass(members, groups):
    gmass = groups['mass']
    gid = groups['groupID']
    mass = [gmass[id==gid] for id in members['groupID']]
    members['groupmass'][:] = mass
```

---

But if `groups['groupID']` can be mapped onto `arange(N)`, then we can get a big jump in speed.  By applying the same mapping to `members['groupID']`, it becomes a simple array indexing problem.

In my sample arrays, `groups['groupID']` is just `arange(N)+101`.  So the mapping just subtracts that minimum.

```
def setmass1(members, groups):
    members['groupmass'][:] = groups['mass'][members['groupID']-groups['groupID'].min()]
```

This is 300x faster than my earlier code, and 8x better than the `pandas` solution (for 10000,500 arrays).

I suspect `pandas` does something like this.  `pgroups.set_index('groupID').mass` is the `mass` Series, with an added `.index` attribute.  (I could test this with a more general array)

In a more general case, it might help to sort `groups`, and if necessary, fill in some indexing gaps.

---

Here's a 'vectorized' solution - no iteration.  But it has to calculate a very large matrix (length of groups by length of members), so does not gain much speed (`np.where` is the slowest step).

```
def setmass2(members, groups):
    idx = np.where(members['groupID'] == groups['groupID'][:,None])
    members['groupmass'][idx[1]] = groups['mass'][idx[0]]
```

Comment: The creation of the mass array can be done *far* faster this in pure numpy, @hpaulj , using numpy.repeat(groups['mass'], group['richness']). This works like greased lightning even for arrays in excess of 1e7 entries. What I was looking for in my question was an analogously fast method to use pure numpy to solve the ID matching problem that I now have a rapid pandas solution for. I am still looking for this.

Comment: If `groups['groupID']` can be mapped onto `arange`, this becomes a simple and fast indexing task.